# C# - Can't get if statement to work as it should - Throw new system.ArgumentException

Tags: c#, wpf, if-statement

I am new to learning C#, and i'm attempting to create a WPF application that asks the user questions. I then convert those answers into strings and export them to a CSV file.

One of the questions is "Pick a number between 1-5". I need to make this so that if a number is less than 1, or more than 5, it asks the user to pick a different number. I tried to achieve this by using the below code. It somewhat works because when i click save as, nothing will happen if i use a wrong number. But it doesn't ask the user like i want it to. Please could someone take a look at my code and let me know why this isn't working?

```
        private void btnSaveClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string firstName = tbFirstName.Text;
                string lastName = tbLastName.Text;
                string jobTitle = tbJobTitle.Text;
                string chickenEgg = tbChickenEgg.Text;
                string _oneFive = tbNumber.Text;
                int oneFive = Convert.ToInt32(_oneFive);

                if ((oneFive > 5) || (oneFive < 1))
                {
                    throw new System.ArgumentException("Please use a number between 1-5");
                }

                string csvContent = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}", FormatCSV(firstName), FormatCSV(lastName), FormatCSV(jobTitle), FormatCSV(chickenEgg), FormatCSV(_oneFive));

                SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
                saveFileDialog.Filter = "CSV file (*.csv)|*.csv";
                if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
                    File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.FileName, csvContent);

                tbFirstName.Clear();
                tbLastName.Clear();
                tbJobTitle.Clear();
                tbChickenEgg.Clear();
                tbNumber.Clear();

                tbFirstName.Focus();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        static string FormatCSV(string _input)
        {

            try
            {
                string result = "";

                if ((_input.Contains(",")) || (_input.Contains(" ")))
                {
                    result = string.Format("\"{0}\"", _input.Trim());
                }
                else
                {
                    result = _input.Trim();
                }


                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
```

When i get to the catch block, nothing displays or seems to happen.

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: What is your expectation? That throwing an Exception is enough to make it ask for a new number?

Comment: Again i'm not sure how the exceptions work. I've only been coding for a few days. I want to have a message pop up, asking for a different number.

Comment: Please show more of your code. What happens in your catch block?

Comment: I will edit my question momentarily.

Comment: I would suggest you to first read about constructs you are using to achieve your goals. `Console.WriteLine` will not display any information to the user in WPF application. Message boxes can be used for this purpose. Furthermore, exception driven code is a bad practice and should be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of throwing an exception, you could display a `MessageBox` to the user:

```
private void btnSaveClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string firstName = tbFirstName.Text;
    string lastName = tbLastName.Text;
    string jobTitle = tbJobTitle.Text;
    string chickenEgg = tbChickenEgg.Text;
    string _oneFive = tbNumber.Text;
    int oneFive = Convert.ToInt32(_oneFive);

    if ((oneFive > 5) || (oneFive < 1))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please use a number between 1-5", "", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }
    else
    {
        string csvContent = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}", FormatCSV(firstName), FormatCSV(lastName), FormatCSV(jobTitle), FormatCSV(chickenEgg), FormatCSV(_oneFive));

        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog.Filter = "CSV file (*.csv)|*.csv";
        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.FileName, csvContent);

        tbFirstName.Clear();
        tbLastName.Clear();
        tbJobTitle.Clear();
        tbChickenEgg.Clear();
        tbNumber.Clear();

        tbFirstName.Focus();
    }
}
```

The user can then click "OK" to dismiss the message box and then enter a new number and hit the "Save" button again. This is basically how GUI applications tend to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to tell the user something, the simple way to do it is with a [message box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.messagebox?view=netframework-4.8)

```
MessageBox.Show("enter a number between 1 and 5");
```

A better, but a little bit more complicated is to use [binding validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-binding-validation). This will reject input as soon as it is entered.

It might be a good idea to read [Best practices for exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions), one rule is to handle common conditions without throwing exceptions, and an incorrect input value would be one of these common cases.

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot, and the additional resources you've provided will help me to better understand it all.